# Approximation ito integral with second order term

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Consider $\int_{t}^{t + \Delta t} a W_s dW_s $, where $a$ is constant.

How do I get the following approximation of this integral: $$ a  \Delta W_t + \frac{1}{2} a^2 
(\Delta W_t)^2$$

Where does the scond term come from? Why do I need that since the integral evaluates to $a (W_{t + \Delta t} -W_t)$?

Comment: There is no reason for you approximation to be true... your integral is simply $a\Delta W_t$... maybe you mean $\int_t^{t+\Delta t}aW_sdW_s$ ?

Comment: Maybe there is mistake in the wiki page. Yes let us assume we have $W_s$ as integrand.

Comment: I got it from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milstein_method

Comment: How do we arive at this formula?

Comment: Use Itô formula...

Comment: For which function should I apply it?

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{a}{2}x^2$.